# Should I use a second router or a WiFi repeater?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I've recently moved to a student house and my room is too far away from the router so I get a very bad WiFi signal in my room. As I do not understand much from internet networks and routers I googled it and it said I had two opportunities: getting a second router or using a WiFi repeater. Which one is a better choice? Can 2 routers be connected to the same network and would that be really difficult? Would I get a better speed with a router than with a WiFi repeater?

Answer (score 1):

A wifi repeater needs a decent signal in order to repeat it. You would have to put it somewhere in the middle of your room and the campus WiFi access point (is not a router) to make it work.

Another option might be a bridge with a directional antenna pointing to the school network. This still may not work well because the signal might be bad enough that even a sensitive directional antenna won't pick it up well. It's basically a repeater when it's done. Then you'd connect the bridge to your laptop. If you want to transmit wifi in your room from that bridge some have the repeater mode (basically it'll be a repeater with a directional antenna) or you can plug your own wifi router into that bridge to create your own network in your room.

Your best bet if you are a paying student in the dorm and your signal is low is request they fix the network.